# Using Ionic 2 with XCode - Update Changes

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic2

Im working currently with XCode / Terminal under Mac OSX. Which command I have to use that my ios platform get updated, when doing changes in the `/src` folder or `config.xml`. Currently only `ionic build ios` works fine, but this takes around 10 minutes. Is there any faster way?

Comment: No there isn't. When using 'ionic build ios', ionic is creating a xCode project for you. So postpone your xCode actions until the last.

Comment: `ionic prepare ios` is enough for testing but you should use build before you go "live" to take advantage of all optimizations made during build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Quick an simple (takes less than 10 secs): `ionic prepare ios`.

When you do `ionic cordova platform add ios`, Ionic creates the Xcode project file (.xcodeproj), then you open that file in Xcode.

When you do `ionic build ios` you're building the .app file for the emulator to run it, but Xcode does that for you anyways when you open the Xcode project and hit the play icon to run the project in the iOS emulator.

Comment: `ionic prepare ios` will update the ios project with the code from your www folder but you will miss many of the optimizations that are made during the build process. During testing `ionic prepare ios` is enough but not for production.

Comment: I usually use `prepare` while in dev, and `build` when ready to ship